# Importing and HTML formatting text from .txt file

Tags: html, string, text, import, formatting

I have a .txt file containing a string of text. This text will appear within  tags and will be formatted accordingly. However, I'm struggling to find a way to import this string and format it also, seeing as though  simply imports the string but does not format it. See:

```
<div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 jumbotron">
  <h1><strong><embed src="contents/title.txt"></strong></h1>
</div>
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong. I'm using this method in order to allow the customer of the website (my Aunt) to update a simple file instead of going through troves of code in order to update the contents of the website. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea but this is a perfect use case for a cms system that has pretty buttons and loads of help. If she were to put in reserved symbols, it's entirely possible the HTML could break. In a CMS however this would be prevented.

Comment: Adding reserved symbols isn't my biggest issue; I'll be able lend support when thing like this happens. The only issue I'm having is getting the text to import and then format.

Comment: Are you sure the txt file is readable server side? Could be a permissions issue.

Comment: It's being done via xampp right now so yes, everything should be okay. The text from the .txt file appears, it isn't formatted however.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by formatted? Can you include the contents of your text file in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to read the content of txt file using html and then wants to apply `<h1>` and `<strong>` tags to it but embed does not do it. It loads txt file as txt not as html.
As you said that you are using xampp, i assume that you are working with php.
you can use this php code to perform what you want

```
<h1><strong>
<?php echo file_get_contents("contents/title.txt"); ?>
</strong></h1>
```

This will apply all formatting to the content of title.txt and you can also use tags in the title.txt, all tags within title.txt will also be formatted.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it would be wise to use a database to do what you want. You could program a management area, with restricted access, where your client could simply change the values ​​of the elements of the site.

Comment: While you're new and eager to answer questions to get your reputation up, this isn't the quality of answer that we expect here at stack. Effectively you've answered a question with a question and no justification or examples included. Not to mention that you haven't actually answered the question being asked. You are on the right path though, I'd recommend using a CMS to manage it but perhaps use the comments in future to pass this on rather than an answer.

Comment: I am not familiar with the policy of stack, I just sign in. I found my answer relevant because I proposed a different vision for fixing the problem. No problem, I would be careful in the future, thank you.
PS: I can not make comments because I do not have 50 reputation.

Comment: If you're not familiar then I'd recommend you read the FAQ. You also had to read stuff before signing up/posting this. Anyway have a read and look at other answers for a guide.